# Deciphering an 1808 Alsatian German birth record

Tags: handwriting

[image: Issenhausen Alsace civil registration birth record]

Having some trouble getting through this civil birth registration record from Issenhausen, Bas-Rhin, Alsace. I've left blanks for words I can't make out. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Maire von Issenhausene Gemeinde ____ von Geburt
von siebenzehnten tag des Monathes 9bre im Jahr eintausent
acht hundert und acht Geburtsabt von Johann George Hässig
Geboren den siebenzehnten 9bre abends um fȕnf uhr Sohn von
Hans Hässig burger und _____ _____ in Issenhause wonhaft und
von Barbara Klopfenstein seiner Ehefrau. das geschlect des
Kindes ist _____ ein Knäblein anbauthend an. Erst anzeig Johannes
Urbar burger und _____ _____ in Issenhausen wonhaft so
zwey und dreissig Jahre alt ist Zweiyt anzeig Jacob Klein burger
und _____ _____ in Issenhausen wohhaft so dreissig Jahre alt ist
und haben sich unterzeichnet.
Johannes Hässig  Hans Urbar  Jacob Klein

Comment: It might be wiser to ask the question on https://genealogy.stackexchange.com, since birth records are their bread and butter.

Comment: "Urban" instead of "Urbar".

Comment: The word after "Sohn von Hans Hässig burger und" could be "Ackersmann"(peasant).

Comment: Thank you, marquinho and Paul Frost!

Comment: Alsace belonged to France since 1618 resp. 1674. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alsace), but had some autonomy till the French Revolution. In 1802 it was fully integrated into the French Republik. During the revolutionary period the salutation "Citoyen" replaced the previous salutations Monsieur, Monsieur le Comte etc. in France and the occupied countries. I guess that "burger" means "Bürger" which is tte German translation of citoyen.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are several errors in your transcription. Here is what I read, changes from your version are marked, where I am in doubt, I added  (?):

> Maire von  Isenhaußen, **Gemeindebezirk von [Zabern](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrondissement_de_Saverne)**
> vom siebenzehnten Tag des Monathes 9bre im Jahr Eindausent
> Achthundert und Acht **Geburts Akt** von Johann Georg Hessig
> Gebohren den siebenzehnten 9bre abents um fünf uhr, sohn von
> Hanß Hessig burger und **Hirt allhie in** Isenhaußen wonhaft, und
> von Barbara Klopfenstein seiner Ehefrau, das Geschlecht des
> Kindes ist **für** ein Knäblein **erkant worden**. Erstanzeig Johannes
> Urban burger und **Ackersmann (?) allhie in** Isenhaußen wonhaft so
> Zwei und dreisig Jahr alt ist, Zweitanzeig Jacob Klein burger
> und **Ackers (?) ebenfals** in Isenhaußen wonhaft so dreisig Jahr alt ist
> und haben sich **unterschrieben ./.**
> Johannes Häsig, Hanß Urban, Jacob Klein
> (?)
>
> Bekreftiget dem Gesez gemeß von mir Johann Georg Lichert (?)
> Maire von Isenhaußen daß Amt eines öffentlichen Beamten des
> Civilstandes versehet, ./. Lichert (?) Maire (?)

Comment: Das (von einer anderen Hand) zwischen bzw. nach den Unterschriften eingeschobene Wort lese ich als "Vorster"; habe aber keine Erklärung dafür.

Comment: Beautiful -- I can see your suggestions clearly. Thank you very much.